# Authentication on your Android App

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am developing an Android App where I require a user to authenticate his session before using the app. One way is to store a user name and password by asking him to register on the app and then use that to authenticate him. But i was looking to do something else, maybe use an OpenId account to authenticate or Opensoial or something like Facebook Connect. Any Suggestions and comments? thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Using OpenID is a great idea in fact. You can use the [**OpenID4Java**](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) library. As you can [read here](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/issues/detail?id=71), someone has modified that project in order to make it Android compatible.

Comment: Hey Cristian, that's really great! But can you throw some more light on using this library. I'm not really sure, how will I be able to integrate this with my app. Many Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone successfully integrated OpenId4Java in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i found this while asking a newer question.

Just an idea but have you looked at the account manager?  What version of android are you targeting?
The sample sync adapter example (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) uses the account manager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)
It looks like a more secure way of using credentials on a native android client because you don't have to store the password at all locally in your app.